# Regex that filters out 7characters in 11th column of csv file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

So I have this csv file casper.csv. It has one line that breaks this database process that runs offshore . So i just
added this to the script that processes the file and it sed's
it out in the script. viola - no phone calls.

```
cd /come/and/play/with/us
    sed -i '/D,642,0642,WOW,MOM,,M,,S,S,DANNNYY,213,213,/d' /come/and/play/with/us/casper.csv
```

Anyhow - I started getting calls at 3am saying that the offshore database process is dying again. There is a different bad line that my sed hack could not catch.
We later discovered that if the 11th column has more than 6 characters it will break the
database process.

The offshore guy used this to find the bad lines:

```
/come/and/play/with/us/casper.csv | perl -nle 'print if /,,,,(.{7}),/'
D,,,WOW,,,M,,,,DANNNYY,-213.00,-213,69036R400
D,,,WOW,,,M,,,,QSP-U=C,-4.00,-4,76090H103
```

So now I use the offshore guy's perl one liner to find out the line that will break the offshore database process, and manually delete it in the file with vi. However I  do not understand how the perl one liner works.
Because it only has 4 commas before the {7} where as is should have 10. and there is not \w or \d before the 7?

```
 perl  -nle 'print if /,,,,(.{7}),/'
```

Most of the regexs that I would build look like this

,\w,\w+,\w+,\w+,\w+,\w+,\w+,\w+,\w+,\w{7},\w+,\w+,

but even this does not work all the time because sometimes there is nothing between the commas  - ie 'D,,,WOW'

The problem is that big boss caught me doing this manually and wants it automated.
I need to add something to the upstream bash script that will kick out any line in the csv file where the 11th column consists of more than 6 characters - these six characters could be anything and sometimes their is nothing (no space) between the commas ... ie 'D,,,WOW'

Comment: Since you are not anchoring your regex (using ^ for the beginging of the string to match, or $ for the end) if floats and can match mid string.

Comment: You may want to use the `*` quantifier instead of the `+` in the second regex. [Here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) is a tutorial to regexes. Or just use `split`.

Comment: may any other columns have more than 6 symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are never any commas in the data itself, you can use

```
 perl -ne 'print if length((split /,/)[10]) > 6' /come/and/play/with/us/casper.csv
```

Of course this prints the lines in error. You can replace the `if` with an `unless` to print the valid lines.

---

**Update**

Or, using Perl's command line options to the full

```
perl -F, -e'print if length $F[10] > 6' /come/and/play/with/us/casper.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, wow. That is a dirty hack if I ever saw one. The `,,,,(.{7}),` regex does not match the 11th column, it matches anything where four commas are followed by seven arbitrary characters followed by a comma. This means that a line

```
D,,,WOW,,,M,,,,DANNNYYY,-213.00,-213,69036R400
           ^^^^1234567^ <-- last one not a comma
```

(with 8 characters in column 11) will not be caught, and a line

```
D,,,,WOWWOWW,,M,,,,DANNNY,-213.00,-213,69036R400
 ^^^^1234567^ <-- match
```

with four commas followed by 7 characters followed by a comma in a different place will. Indeed, since there is nothing in the 7 characters that prevents it from matching other commas,

```
D,,,,WOW,,M,,,,DANNNYYY,-213.00,-213,69036R400
 ^^^^1234567^ <-- match
```

will also be considered broken.

If it were me, I'd use awk to filter out broken lines.

```
awk -F, 'length($11) < 7' /come/and/play/with/us/casper.csv
```

will print all lines in casper.csv in which the 11th field is less than 7 characters long. If you have a recent GNU awk (4.1.0 or later), you can use

```
awk -i inplace -F, 'length($11) < 7' /come/and/play/with/us/casper.csv
```

to change the file in place, although personally I'd like to have the original around just in case.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\([^,]*,\){\10\}[^,]\{7\}/d' file
```

This will delete lines with 7 or more characters in the 11th field of a pure CSV file assuming `,` is the only delimiter. It looks for ten fields which contain zero or more non-comma characters followed by a comma ,starting from the beginning of the line and finally tries to match seven non-comma characters in the 11th field.